# PHP How to get the url of the page where include is used

Tags: php, html, url

I have an Index.php with this line:

`<?php echo (file_get_contents("http://www.mydomain.com/includes/header.php")); ?>`

In the header.php I would like to include a DIV secion only if the visitor is on www.mydomain.com/index.php on the rest I would like to Hide this.

I figured to use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and `REQUEST_URI` to get the location and then use an IF to check if the page is index.php ELSE dont show the DIV section.

The problem is, if I get it into the header.php I get the url to be www.mydomain.com/includes/header.php insted of www.mydomain.com/index.php

Any Idea how to get over this problem?

Comment: why file_get_contents instea of a regular include??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you want to use file_get_contents? You could use `include_once('header.php');`. in your index.php file. Determining if you are on index.php page you can use in your header.php file

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "index.php") { 
    /* show whatever you need */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use define a variable based on $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] variable. So, within the index.php file, you would define it first, and then include the header file.

```
$thisPage = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
include('includes/header.php');
```

Then, in the header.php file, an if statement:

```
if ($thisPage == 'index.php'){
    //all the code
    //echo this, that, and the other
}
```